# Gradle: What Is The Default Configuration and How Do I Change It

Tags: gradle

When I run the "dependencies" task there are several sections: compile, runtime, testCompile ...

One of those sections is "default - Configuration for default artifacts." What is this section and what is it used for?

How do I change what is in the "default configuration"?

***Details:** Gradle 1.7*

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Unless your build is publishing Ivy modules, the `default` configuration is mainly relevant when dealing with *project dependencies* in a multi-project build. Given a multi-project build with projects A and B, if A declares a project dependency on B without explicitly naming a configuration (e.g. `dependencies { compile project(":B") }`, A (more precisely A's `compile` configuration) will depend on project B's `default` configuration. In other words, `dependencies { compile project(":B") }` is a shortcut for `dependencies { compile project(path: ":B", configuration: "default") }`.

The `default` configuration extends from the `runtime` configuration, which means that it contains all the dependencies and artifacts of the `runtime` configuration, and potentially more. You can add dependencies and artifacts in the usual way (using a `dependencies`/`artifacts` block in B's build script). Alternatively, B could declare a custom configuration, and A could depend on that by explicitly naming that configuration (e.g. `dependencies { compile project(path: ":B", configuration: "myCustomConfig") }`.

Comment: I still wonder if you can set the default configuration to something else than "runtime".

Comment: I don't fully get it. So runtime = default ?

Answer (score 5):

When using the gradle java plugin the 'default' configuration extendsFrom 'runtime', 'runtimeOnly', 'implementation'

If you do not use the java plugin then you can define it yourself like this

```
configurations {
    "default"
}
```

The java plugin sets up the default configuration here: https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/85d30969f4672bb2739550b4de784910a6810b7a/subprojects/plugins/src/main/java/org/gradle/api/plugins/JavaPlugin.java#L437

The documentation is not that good in this area.

An example of "serving" a default artifact from a composite build.
The example creates a subproject that refers to a dependency in another project. This can be nessesary when working with composite builds, as only the "default" group can be depended upon.

We use this to take many jars from a single project and serve it as different dependencies when referencing the project as a composite build.

```
apply plugin: 'base'

configurations {
    depend
}

dependencies {
    depend project(path: ':', configuration: 'ConfWithArtifact')
}

artifacts {
    "default" (file: configurations.depend.singleFile) {
        builtBy(configurations.depend)
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a source for this? I've been looking for some documentation on this `default` configuration, but have yet to find any.

Comment: Added link to where the configuration is setup.

Comment: Documentation is super bad regarding this :(. And how is that handled in composite builds?

Comment: I added an example from a project i have worked on previously.

Answer (score 0):

The `default` configuration is actually created by the `base` plugin, and so you don't need to define it yourself.

I've also had the problem with composite builds only compositing from the `default` configuration, but I solved it slightly differently:

```
plugins {
    id 'base'
}

configurations {
    bootstrap
    it.'default'.extendsFrom bootstrap
}

dependencies {
    bootstrap project(path: ':other', configuration: 'otherConfiguration')
}
```

This approach allows the artifact from the `:other` project to keep its transitive dependencies, assuming you're interested in keeping them.