# Java-Library dependencies not being imported when jar is depended on

Tags: java, gradle

I am attempting to move some commonly used modules into their own project so they can be uploaded to a private repository and used in applications. Currently, they are all in one multi-project configuration and everything works as expected. I moved them out and it all seems to build fine. When I use them as dependencies in my applications, I get errors that say `java.lang.module.FindException: Module X not found, required by COMMON-MODULE-Y`.

I was under the impression that the `java-library` plugin allowed my application to import those secondary dependencies that were needed by the dependencies declared, and this is not what is happening.

How can I package my commonly used modules to allow this OR how can i configure my project to allow for this? I am using Java 11 for this.

> EDIT

Basically I want my libraries to be self contained and the applications that use them to not include any additional libraries.

Here is my `build.gradle` for the module I am getting the above error on.

```
plugins {
    id 'java-library'
    id 'idea'
}

if(project.hasProperty('javaVer') && javaVer == '8') {
    sourceCompatibility = 1.8
    targetCompatibility = 1.8
}

idea {
    module {
        inheritOutputDirs = true
    }
}

def currentOS = org.gradle.internal.os.OperatingSystem.current()
def depPlatform

if (!project.hasProperty(('platform'))) {
    if (currentOS.isWindows()) {
        depPlatform = 'win'
    } else if (currentOS.isLinux()) {
        depPlatform = 'linux'
    } else if (currentOS.isMacOsX()) {
        depPlatform = 'mac'cd
    }
}else {
    depPlatform = project.getProperties().get("platform");
}

sourceSets.main {
    java {
        srcDir 'src/main/java' //assume that your source codes are inside this path
    }
    resources {
        srcDirs = ['src/main/java', 'src/main/resources']
        exclude "**/*.java"
    }
}

ext.moduleName = 'license'

dependencies {
    implementation project(':common')
    implementation "org.openjfx:javafx-base:11.0.2:${depPlatform}"
    implementation 'commons-io:commons-io:2.6'
    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.7'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
    implementation 'com.github.purejavacomm:purejavacomm:1.0.1.RELEASE'
}
```

Here is the `build.gradle` for the multi-project the above module is in.

```
subprojects {
    afterEvaluate {
        repositories {
            mavenCentral()
            jcenter()
        }

        compileJava {
            if (project.hasProperty(('javaVer')) && javaVer == '8') {
                excludes = ['**/module-info.java']
            } else {
                doFirst {
                    options.compilerArgs = [
                        '--module-path', classpath.asPath,
                    ]
                }
            }
        }

        jar {
            archiveFileName = project.name + '-' + (project.hasProperty(('releaseSpec')) ? project.releaseSpec : 'SNAPSHOT') + '.jar'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this may be a result of missing entries in the dependency jars manifests, outlined here in the oracle java docs. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: you want to [expose](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management_terminology.html#sub:terminology_transitive_dependency) [runtime dependencies](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_dependencies.html). E.g. they are needed for application execution, however they shouldn't be available for compilation.

Please use the following workable code:

settings.gradle.kts:

```
include(":application")
include(":libraryA")
include(":libraryB")
```

application/gradle.build.kts:

```
plugins {
    application
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.3.61"
}

dependencies {
    api(project(":libraryA")) // we reference only library, we know nothing about the dependencies.
}
```

libraryA/gradle.build.kts:

```
plugins {
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.3.61"
}

dependencies {
    api(project(":libraryB")) // again, we know nothing about the dependencies
}
```

libraryB/gradle.build.kts:

```
plugins {
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.3.61"
}

dependencies {
    api("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.3.61")
   // api("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-reactor:1.3.3") - uncomment this line to expose api. You will see kotlinx-coroutines-reactor members in intellisence
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-reactor:1.3.3") // mark, that this dependency is needed for compilation. However it will not be exposed to other project.
    runtimeOnly("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-reactor:1.3.3") // mark, that this dependency is required for runtime. It means, that it will be exposed as runtime dependency only
}
```

libraryB\src\Something.kt

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.runBlocking

fun doSomething() {
    runBlocking { // use kotlinx-coroutines here.
        println("Yess !!!")
    }
}
```

application\src\Application.kt

```
package gradle.multi.application

import doSomething

fun main() {
    "12314".toInt() // check, that api layer is exposed here

    /* runBlocking { // this couldn't be compiled, because kotlinx-coroutines aren't exposed here
    }*/

    doSomething()
}
```

So, what we did:

- Our dependencies: `application` --> `libraryA` --> `libraryB`
- `application` is runnable project, all other are just libraries.
- `libraryA` doesn't have any words to re-expose dependency. It just references `libraryB`
- `application` just references `libraryA`. Developer doesn't know about any implicit dependencies (compile or runtime).
- `libraryB` uses `kotlinx-coroutines-reactor` and exposes it as runtime dependency. And this information is published through `libraryA` to the runnable project.

Comment: This did not fix my problem. I want all of these dependencies to be internal to this module. From reading your links that means I use `implementation`. When my application uses this module as a dependency, it should not need to declare the libraries that the module depends on, and right now it is forcing me to. Not sure if this matters but I am using Java 11. I will add that to my question.

Comment: If your library exposes dependencies (e.g. "api") then they will be accessible for anyone who references it. E.g. if A references B, which references C then A will able to work with any public class/method from C. Maven repositories (please note, that gradle tries to work with dependencies in the same way with Maven) doesn't have "hidden dependencies", you must expose all of them. However if you want to keep all necessary code inside jar, you can store all dependencies at the resources and use ClassLoader to load them into memory. This solution is risky, because you can receive class hell.

Comment: Okay that does make sense. What about if A does not need to use anything from C? I would then use `implementation` for C in B, would I not?

Comment: @HypnicJerk, I reworked answer. Looks like it is what you need.