# How to have action button on action bar - Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-activity, android-menu

I wrote in activity

```
   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.add_action,menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

I wrote in menu file

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/add"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_add_circle_outline_black_24dp"
    android:title="@string/add"
   />
```

**The error is still showing, any ideas ?**

[image]

Comment: What error it is showing ?

Comment: file:///C:/Users/ABHISHEK/Downloads/Alt-Tag-android-popup-menu-in-android.png                                                      this what i m getting

Comment: mean you are not able to get that image that you have set here

Comment: check my answer and tell if issue still not solved

Comment: defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.abhishek.office"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }    in build grade all version

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19941894/2826147

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add

```
app:showAsAction="always"
```

Add image to **res/drawable/Alt-Tag-android-popup-menu-in-android**.

Comment: Error:(5) Error parsing XML: unbound prefix     showing this type of error

Comment: ADD <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"> in xml

Comment: if u have team view then u can check it if u have time

Comment: please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2221221/frequent-issues-arising-in-android-view-error-parsing-xml-unbound-prefix

Comment: from last 2 day im trying every thing if u hv time thn check it using team- view please

Comment: ok :( if  possible please help me i have lost all my time searching all this please :(

Comment: will inform you once i get team viewer in evening

Comment: please accept my answer if your issue is solved. @AbhiKhatua

Comment: is there any provision to change the color of icon  in android as u can see  above @Amit vaghela

Comment: you should replace icon instead of changing color.

Comment: i'm getting the icon in black or white from android official page but how to get the icon of blue color...

Comment: you have to generate that.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that this is your only icon, change ifRoom to always. it is not recommended.

If that does not help, add this line to the top of your menu

xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

Comment: no not working all this can any one help me out please

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/add"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="@string/add"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_add_circle_outline_black_24dp"
        app:showAsAction="always"/>

    </menu>
```