# use configuration that was created in one project in another

Tags: java, gradle

I have a multiproject build with `domain`, `service` and so on projets.

I defined a configuration in my `domain` project that supposed to use a support class stored in `test` path (it would be better to reference a single class though as I need only single `BaseTestClass` from tests).

```
configurations {
    testSupport
}

dependencies {
    testSupport sourceSets.test.output
}
```

Then I use it in my another project like this

```
testCompile project(path: ":domain", configuration: 'testSupport')
```

Is there a way to use it like this?

```
testSupport project(":domain")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
testCompile project(":domain")
```

Is equivalent to

```
testCompile project(path: ":domain", configuration: 'default')
```

So, I suggest you add to the 'default' configuration rather than creating a 'testSupport' configuration. Note that 'default' is a reserved word in java/groovy so you might need quotes/brackets. Eg:

```
dependencies {
    'default'(sourceSets.test.output) 
}
```

Or perhaps this is nicer

```
dependencies.add('default', sourceSets.test.output)
```

More information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19936915/gradle-what-is-the-default-configuration-and-how-do-i-change-it)