# gradle default configuration, what is it and how can I define it

Tags: gradle

I am having a weird error, for which I found a lot of hits in google but most about android studio or library imports and I don't use android studio nor am I trying to build any app/library so I'll try and ask here and see if I understand the background of it.

I have a project in which I have this plugin:
https://gitlab.com/zkovari/gradle-mermaid-plugin/-/blob/master/examples/single-project/build.gradle

This is a plugin that displays my dependencies as a mermaid graph.

Everything was fine until today I updated some dependencies and created a sub-project to do something else.
I'm trying to generate the graph again and somehow it's failing with this error message.

```
> Task :generateMermaidDependenciesDiagram FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':generateMermaidDependenciesDiagram'.
> Configuration with name 'default' not found.
```

I can see in the source code of the plugin that it automatically sets some configurations

```
@Override
public void apply(Project project) {
    GenerateMermaidDependenciesDiagram generateDependencyDiagramsTask = project.getTasks()
            .create(GENERATE_MERMAID_DEPENDENCIES_DIAGRAM_TASK_NAME, GenerateMermaidDependenciesDiagram.class);
    generateDependencyDiagramsTask.setConfiguration("default");
    generateDependencyDiagramsTask
            .setOutput(project.getBuildDir().toPath().resolve("mermaid/dependencies.mmd").toFile());
    generateDependencyDiagramsTask.setDiagramGenerator(new MermaidDiagramGenerator());
}
```

So my question is a bit high level but what is the "default" configuration?
And in my project I don't really have any configuration block I simply have my dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    implementation group: 'com.amazonaws', name: 'aws-java-sdk-s3', version: awsVersion, transitive: false
...
    testCompile group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-simple', version: slf4jVersion
}
```

My structure looks like this:

- project:
  -- build.gradle
  -- settings.gradle
  -- sub-project:
  --- build.gradle

I think this stopped working when I added my sub-project but the plugin is applied at the root project level.
I do have a dependency between my sub-project and my root project (one of my sub-project tasks depends on the root project)

I'm trying to understand that this might be very similar but I'm not fully getting it.

[Gradle: What Is The Default Configuration and How Do I Change It](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19936915/gradle-what-is-the-default-configuration-and-how-do-i-change-it)

I do apply the java plugin on my main project so I expect the configuration.default should exist.

Even if I think I shouldn't do it I tried to re-define a default configuration extending implementation but that did not work
https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_dependencies.html

```
configurations {
    default.extendsFrom implementation
}
build file 'C:\dev\repo\connector-custom\build.gradle': 66: unexpected token: default @ line 66, column 5.
default.extendsFrom implementation
```

I did a quick test and removing my subproject did work so I know the problem is there but no idea why.
It means somehow I must pass to my subproject the default configuration of the main project?

Comment: The default configuration is the default configuration.

Comment: thanks but why would it not exist?